# Difficulty Understanding Primary Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have read that any irreducible sub-module $I$ of a Noetherian module $M$ is primary.  However if we let $M = \mathbb{Z}_8$ and $I = \mathbb{4Z}_8$  this isn't true, because $I$ is irreducible, and $2(M/I) = 2(\mathbb{Z}_4) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Thus multiplication by 2 is neither injective nor nilpotent.  How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the multiplication by $2$ *is* nilpotent since $4(M/I)=0$.